# How to use IndexedDB in Angular?

Tags: javascript, database, angular, reactjs, typescript

Is there somewhere a material to use the indexedDB in Angular? I am looking for something that helps me to implement in data rescue or better, a database that is in the browser, although it is not the localstore because of the limitation of 5 MB

Comment: You can use it as you would with any other framework.

Comment: Numerous libraries around for it. Native API is not as intuitive as it could be, using a library makes it simpler

Comment: check out this article - http://ujjwalguptaofficial.blogspot.in/2017/10/angular4-crud-operation-in-indexeddb.html

Comment: I used DexiesJs :D

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-indexed-db

Comment: Use npm library name idb

Comment: I found this really easy to use https://dexie.org/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I use [Dexie](https://dexie.org) as it's a more mature and lightweight library and with all features.
Compatible with VueJs, React, Angular and Vanilla JS

Alternative [ngx-indexed-db](https://npmjs.com/package/ngx-indexed-db)

Answer (score 5):

use ngx-indexed-db npm library:

```
npm install ngx-indexed-db
```

Import the NgxIndexedDBModule and initiate it:

```
import { NgxIndexedDBModule } from 'ngx-indexed-db';

const dbConfig: DBConfig  = {
  name: 'MyDb',
  version: 1,
  objectStoresMeta: [{
    store: 'people',
    storeConfig: { keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement: true },
    storeSchema: [
      { name: 'name', keypath: 'name', options: { unique: false } },
      { name: 'email', keypath: 'email', options: { unique: false } }
    ]
  }]
};

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    ...
    NgxIndexedDBModule.forRoot(dbConfig)
  ],
  ...
})
```

Migrations:

```
import { NgxIndexedDBModule, DBConfig } from 'ngx-indexed-db';

// Ahead of time compiles requires an exported function for factories
export function migrationFactory() {
  // The animal table was added with version 2 but none of the existing tables or data needed
  // to be modified so a migrator for that version is not included.
  return {
    1: (db, transaction) => {
      const store = transaction.objectStore('people');
      store.createIndex('country', 'country', { unique: false });
    },
    3: (db, transaction) => {
      const store = transaction.objectStore('people');
      store.createIndex('age', 'age', { unique: false });
    }
  };
}

const dbConfig: DBConfig  = {
  name: 'MyDb',
  version: 3,
  objectStoresMeta: [{
    store: 'people',
    storeConfig: { keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement: true },
    storeSchema: [
      { name: 'name', keypath: 'name', options: { unique: false } },
      { name: 'email', keypath: 'email', options: { unique: false } }
    ]
  }, {
    // animals added in version 2
    store: 'animals',
    storeConfig: { keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement: true },
    storeSchema: [
      { name: 'name', keypath: 'name', options: { unique: true } },
    ]
  }],
  // provide the migration factory to the DBConfig
  migrationFactory
};

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    ...
    NgxIndexedDBModule.forRoot(dbConfig)
  ],
  ...
})
```

NgxIndexedDB service
First, import the service:

```
import { NgxIndexedDBService } from 'ngx-indexed-db';

...
  export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private dbService: NgxIndexedDBService){
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way to use IndexedDB. A lightweight, minimalistic wrapper that provides a straightforward API for developers using IndexedDB shared below a link

https://dexie.org

Answer (score 0):

For use Dexie in angular you need install [Dexie.Observable](https://dexie.org/docs/Observable/Dexie.Observable).